# I get errors when returned data from the method using web services references

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I write my web services (asmx) as

```
[WebMethod]
//public List<Ahlam> GetBloodGroup(String gblood)
public DataSet GetBloodGroup(string gblood)
{
        string bloodgroup = gblood.ToString();
        string ApoloConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnSApolo"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ApoloConn);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select name as 'NAME', blood_group as 'BLOOD GROUP', gender as 'GENDER' , city as 'CITY' , mobile as 'MOBILE' " +
            "from dontable where blood_group = @bloodgroup", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bloodgroup", bloodgroup);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds1);

        return ds1;
 }
```

And this is the buttonAction when it's pressed to call the function in my web service

```
protected void search_bloodgroup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
      string bg = bloodlist.SelectedItem.Text;
      AhlamQueryGroup.AhlamQueryBloodSoapClient client = new 
      AhlamQueryGroup.AhlamQueryBloodSoapClient();

      DataSet set = client.GetBloodGroup(bg);
      gridview_Donate.DataSource = set;
}
```

This is in the `web.config` of my project

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnSApolo" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ApoloDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And this is the `web.config` in my web services project

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnSApolo" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ApoloDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I press the button I get this error

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file E:\Ahlam\BloodHospital_project\Blood_Hospital_banks_project\WebServices\WebServices\App_Data\ApoloDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity  identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, BooleanapplyTransientFaultHandling)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)   at
>   WebServices.AhlamQueryBlood.GetBloodGroup(String gblood) in
>   E:\Ahlam\BloodHospital_project\Blood_Hospital_banks_project\WebServices\WebServices\AhlamQueryBlood.asmx.cs:line
>   40   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt
>   to attach an auto-named database for file
>   E:\Ahlam\BloodHospital_project\Blood_Hospital_banks_project\WebServices\WebServices\App_Data\ApoloDB.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share.   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)   at
>   WebServices.AhlamQueryBlood.GetBloodGroup(String gblood) in
>   E:\Ahlam\BloodHospital_project\Blood_Hospital_banks_project\WebServices\WebServices\AhlamQueryBlood.asmx.cs:line
>   40   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 53:          Line 54:         public System.Data.DataSet
>   GetBloodGroup(string gblood) { Line 55:             return
>   base.Channel.GetBloodGroup(gblood); Line 56:         } Line 57:
>
> Source File:
>   E:\Ahlam\BloodHospital_project\Blood_Hospital_banks_project\BloodBank\BloodBank\Connected
>   Services\AhlamQueryGroup\Reference.cs    Line: 55
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FaultException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server
>   was unable to process request. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named
>   database for file
>   E:\Ahlam\BloodHospital_project\Blood_Hospital_banks_project\WebServices\WebServices\App_Data\ApoloDB.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)    at
>   WebServices.AhlamQueryBlood.GetBloodGroup(String gblood) in
>   E:\Ahlam\BloodHospital_project\Blood_Hospital_banks_project\WebServices\WebServices\AhlamQueryBlood.asmx.cs:line
>   40    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---]
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +153
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) +336
>   BloodBank.AhlamQueryGroup.AhlamQueryBloodSoap.GetBloodGroup(String
>   gblood) +0
>   BloodBank.AhlamQueryGroup.AhlamQueryBloodSoapClient.GetBloodGroup(String
>   gblood) in
>   E:\Ahlam\BloodHospital_project\Blood_Hospital_banks_project\BloodBank\BloodBank\Connected
>   Services\AhlamQueryGroup\Reference.cs:55
>   BloodBank.FilterDonor.search_bloodgroup_Click(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in
>   E:\Ahlam\BloodHospital_project\Blood_Hospital_banks_project\BloodBank\BloodBank\FilterDonor.aspx.cs:40
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9669714
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +108
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +12
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3562at

this is the reference of my webreferences in the my project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9LHY.png)
this is the web services in the webservices project in the same solution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na6dP.png)

I tried to remove connectionString from web.config in my webservices project but I get another error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOMNP.png) 
when I press continue I get the same first error

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the full stacktrace of the exceptions as text, not as images (screenshots)

Answer (score 0):

To Simulate the issue:

First thing you have to do is..

Create new normal project (Not a web service project) then run your function if it is working or not.

```
public DataSet GetBloodGroup(string gblood)
{
        string bloodgroup = gblood.ToString();
        string ApoloConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnSApolo"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ApoloConn);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select name as 'NAME', blood_group as 'BLOOD GROUP', gender as 'GENDER' , city as 'CITY' , mobile as 'MOBILE' " +
            "from dontable where blood_group = @bloodgroup", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bloodgroup", bloodgroup);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds1);

        return ds1;
 }
```

Something like:

```
DataSet dsSimulate = new DataSet();
dsSimulate = GetBloodGroup("YourbloodValueHere");
```

Then run it in debug mode to get and check the error.

Your error occur and it says (`You already has a database name`). Try to check if it is exists or not.

**Reminder:**

Before you do to use and run your `Web Service`, you have to make sure if it is working in Normal Debug mode.

There are possible two ways of problem.. It's either your function has an error or the deployment itself upon calling your Web Service.

**when Adding Web Service into your project reference:**

Web.Config File(`Project Calling the Web Service`)
It must look like this after you done adding the service reference deployed link at your project.

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1750/Service1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap" contract="Service1.Service1Soap"
        name="Service1Soap" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1750/Service1.asmx" binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap12" contract="Service1.Service1Soap"
        name="Service1Soap12" />
    </client>
```

In you Code Behind:

```
 Service1.Service1SoapClient cli;

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    cli = new Service1.Service1SoapClient("Service1Soap12");
    cli.GetBloodGroup("BloodGourHere");//this line returns your DataSet
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: see, I did this and the function works. Also, I tried to make the web service with my project (in the same project without references) .. and it works..

Comment: I want to make this web services separately and call its reference .. that is where I met the error.

Comment: Try to check the folder permission of this..`E:\Ahlam\BloodHospital_project\Blood_Hospital_banks_project\WebServices\WebServices\App_Data\ApoloDB.mdf`

Comment: I don't know how can I check the permission {I use local database in the same project }..